# How to find the general xpath of a WebElement in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've to find the correct login form in a webpage (it has to work in different sites so I cannot simply use the id or similar becausa can obviously change for different sites).

What I do is to find all the form and than to try to find the one with only three element (user, password and access-button)

```
user_field_list = ["username", "email", "user", "prova", "login_email", "session[username_or_email]"]
pass_field_list = ["password","Password", "pass", "login_password", "session[password]"]
button_field_list = ["Accedi", "login", "access", "Avanti"]
for form in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//form'):
   count=0
   find_user=0
   find_pass=0
   find_button=0
   for input_field in form.find_elements_by_xpath('.//input'):
      if (input_field.get_attribute("type") not in "hidden"):
         count=count+1
      if(find_pass == 0):
          for passkey in pass_field_list:
              if (passkey in input_field.get_attribute("type")):
                find_pass = 1
      if (find_user==0):
          for userkey in user_field_list:
             if (userkey in input_field.get_attribute("type")):
                find_user=1
      if (find_button==0):
          if ("submit" in input_field.get_attribute("type")):
              find_button=1
```

With some debug I've verified that it found the correct form, but in the end of this part I've to pass a reference to the three fields to another function that has to do the login

```
def general_login(browser, xpath_user, xpath_pass, xpath_button):
    print("general_login")
    try:
        print("System Log: SEARCH FOR USER FIELD ")
        print (str(xpath_user))
        username = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_user)
        print("System Log: FOUND USER FIELD")
        username.send_keys(usernameStr)
        print("System Log: SEARCH FOR PASSWORD FIELD")
        password = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_pass)
        print("System Log: FOUND PASSWORD FIELD")
        password.send_keys(passwordStr)
        print("System Log: SEARCH FOR BUTTON ACCEDI")
        accediButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_button)
        print("System Log: FOUND BUTTON ACCEDI")
        accediButton.click()
        return 0
    except:
        return 1
```

The problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the three general xpaths from the webElements (And I haven't an alternative idea in how to pass the correct references to the function).

Someone can help me in how to retrieve the xpaths or other possibilities that I can use? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass elements to `general_login` instead of trying to get `xpath` from WebElement.

Below `get_form_fields` method return empty or with form fields dictionary. If dictionary is empty `general_login` will fail:

```
def get_form_fields(browser, user_field_types, password_field_types, button_types):
    # get form fields as dictionary with keys: user_field, password_field, submit_button

    form_fields = {}
    for form in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//form'):

        inputs = list(filter(lambda x: x.is_displayed(), form.find_elements_by_xpath('.//input')))
        if len(inputs) < 3:
            continue

        user_field_list = list(filter(lambda x: x.get_attribute("type") in user_field_types, inputs))
        if len(user_field_list) != 1:
            form_fields.clear()
            continue
        else:
            form_fields["user_field"] = user_field_list[0]

        password_field_list = list(filter(lambda x: x.get_attribute("type") in password_field_types, inputs))
        if len(password_field_list) != 1:
            form_fields.clear()
            continue
        else:
            form_fields["password_field"] = password_field_list[0]

        button_list = list(filter(lambda x: x.get_attribute("type") in button_types, inputs))
        if len(button_list) != 1:
            form_fields.clear()
            continue
        else:
            form_fields["submit_button"] = button_list[0]

    return form_fields
```

And `general_login` use:

```
def general_login():
    user_field_types = ["username", "email", "user", "prova", "login_email", "session[username_or_email]"]
    password_field_types = ["password", "Password", "pass", "login_password", "session[password]"]
    button_types = ["Accedi", "login", "access", "Avanti"]
    form_fields = get_form_fields(browser, user_field_types, password_field_types, button_types)

    assert form_fields

    print("general_login")
    print("System Log: SEARCH FOR USER FIELD ")
    form_fields["user_field"].send_keys(username)

    print("System Log: SEARCH FOR PASSWORD FIELD")
    form_fields["password_field"].send_keys(password)

    print("System Log: SEARCH FOR BUTTON ACCEDI")
    form_fields["submit_button"].click()


browser = webdriver.Chrome()

username = "user"
password = "password"

general_login()
```

Comment: Thank you! I think that your code still has something wrong since I've tried and it not finds the correct form, but I've tried with my code passing the webElement instead of the xpath (as you suggest!) and it works!!! thank you again!